# Sorting alphabets within a string

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a pair of string like:

```
JAY, ROB
```

Is there a way with javascript, where I could create a new word from these 2 words where the preceding alphabet is always greater than equal to the next (for e.g. A is greater than B)

For example, in the above string I want to compare the first letter of `JAY` with the first letter of `ROB`. Since `J` comes first when compared with `R`, the first alphabet of the new word will be `J`. Comparing the second, since `A` comes before `R` it becomes the second alphabet, the third alphabet similarly becomes `R`.

So the final word would be `JAROBY`

I have no clue on how could I approach this. I was thinking if I could use the `sort` function somehow but could not understand how.

I was trying something similar to:

```
var a = `JAY,ROB`;
var sorted = a.split(",").sort()
var firstLetter = sorted[0][0];
```

Note: There could be more than a pair. For example, `JAY, ROB, APPLE, AAKO`

Comment: This looks like merge routine in merge sort.

Comment: The question srems unclear. Please describe at least two examples, where all choices for each example construction are clearly detailed. (Even for your one current example, the exact choices made in the construction are not clear.)

Answer (score 1):

I'd make two arrays out of the input words, and use a loop. On each iteration, check which array's value at the 0th index comes first, and if it does, `shift` it (removing it from the array) and concatenate it with the output string:

```js
const input = 'JAY, ROB';
const [arr1, arr2] = input.split(', ').map(word => [...word]);

let output = '';
while (arr1.length || arr2.length) {
  if (arr2.length && arr1[0] > arr2[0]) {
    output += arr2.shift();
  } else {
    output += arr1.shift();
  }
}
console.log(output);
```

Or, for any number of words:

```js
const input = 'APPLE, JUICE';
const arrOfArrs = input.split(', ').map(word => [...word]);

let output = '';
while (arrOfArrs.some(arr => arr.length)) {
  const firstLetters = arrOfArrs.map(arr => arr[0] || '');
  const lowestChar = firstLetters.reduce((a, b) => b && (b < a || !a) ? b : a);
  const indexOfWordWithLowestStartingChar = firstLetters.indexOf(lowestChar);
  output += arrOfArrs[indexOfWordWithLowestStartingChar].shift();
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Is there a way to extend this to input string of any size? For example, `JAY, ROB, APPLE` or `JAY, ROB, APPLE, MOON, AAKKO`?

Comment: Looks like this method fails if I try an input string `APPLE, JUICE`. It just hangs.

Comment: Think I fixed it, check if the accumulator exists in the reduce callback, otherwise the `<` test will undesirably fail if the accumulator is the empty string

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer that can work for any size of string.
It's an "easy" answer, certainly not the most optimized, but it can be easely understood by anyone.

```js
var a = `JAY,ROB,APPLE,AAKO`;
var nbOfLetters = a.replace(/,/g, "").length;

let result = "";
var sorted = a.split(",").sort(specialSort);

while (result.length < nbOfLetters)
{
    result += sorted[0][0];
    sorted[0] = sorted[0].slice(1);
    sorted = sorted.sort(specialSort);
}

console.log("result", result);

function specialSort(a, b) {
    if(a === "" || a === null) return 1;
    if(b === "" || b === null) return -1;
    if(a === b) return 0;
  
    return a < b ? -1 : 1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1s9axLzu/

Answer (score 0):

A solution for multiple strings.

```js
function getSorta(string) {
    var iterators = string.split(', ').map(s => {
            var i = [...s][Symbol.iterator]();
            return [i.next(), i]
        }),
        result = '';

    do {
        iterators.sort((a, b) => a[0].done - b[0].done || (a[0].value || '').localeCompare(b[0].value || ''));
        console.log(...iterators.map(([{ value }]) => value || ' '));
        result += iterators[0][0].value;
        iterators[0][0] = iterators[0][1].next();
    } while (!iterators.every(([{ done }]) => done))

    return result;
}

console.log(getSorta('JAY, ROB'));
console.log(getSorta('JAY, ROB, APPLE, MOON, AAKKO'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```